# avformat_open_input() fails to open url

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to open URL using avformat_open_input API function. 
Initially, I got a warning like,

**Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.**

After initializing **avformat_network_init()**, I am getting a negative return value for avformat_open_input() function call.

**INPUT URL: https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8**

Can anyone please help me to find the issue?